# Solving Quadratic Equation Equal to 0 in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to the python language and I'm trying to write a program to solve for a bunch of time/distance/acceleration variables. I know I need some kind of solve function to use in the Dtot-Dacceleration-Dconstant-Dbraking=0 line, but I don't know what function to use or what the syntax is for it. Here's my code for one chunk of it, any help would be appreciated!

```
def VehicleProfile(Vi, Fa, Fd, Dtot, Vf, Taccel):

    Vconstant = Vi+(Fa*9.81*Taccel)
    Dacceleration = (Vi*Taccel)+(.5*Fa*9.81*(Taccel**2))
    Dconstant = Vconstant*Tconstant
    Dbraking = ((Vf**2)-(Vconstant**2))/(2*Fd*9.81)
    Tbraking = (Vf-Vconstant)/(Fd*9.81)
    Dtot-Dacceleration-Dconstant-Dbraking=0
    return (Tconstant, Tbraking)
```

Also I'm using python 2.7.7

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula

Comment: You're using `Tconstant` in `Dconstant = Vconstant*Tconstant` before it has been given a value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just rearrange it

```
Dtot = Dacceleration + Dconstant + Dbraking
```

Everything on the right hand side is already known at this point.

Comment: There's more wrong with this function than that one line.

Comment: They've changed the function a few times since I answered, but assuming they have the variables on the right side, which it seems like they will have calculated, it is just algebra to solve for `Dtot` as I have written.

Answer (score 0):

I've made the necessary changes to get this function to work.

```
def VehicleProfile(Vi, Fa, Fd, Dtot, Vf, Taccel):
    Vconstant = Vi+(Fa*9.81*Taccel)
    Dacceleration = (Vi*Taccel)+(.5*Fa*9.81*(Taccel**2))
    Dbraking = ((Vf**2)-(Vconstant**2))/(2*Fd*9.81)
    Tbraking = (Vf-Vconstant)/(Fd*9.81)
    Dconstant = Dtot-Dacceleration-Dbraking
    Tconstant = Dconstant/Vconstant
    return (Tconstant, Tbraking)
```

What you need to understand as a foundation of programming is that the variable on the left of a `=` sign is where the answer to the expression on the right gets saved. You had Tconstant on the right side of the equation and tried to return it later. That equation also used `Dconstant`, which had not yet been calculated because the lines are run from top to bottom.